# Compile time consistent hash of char types

Tags: c++, hash, c++11, user-defined-literals

I want to implement of sort of `Symbol` the same way ruby does.

For this, I created a user defined literal which returned a `std::hash` of the `std::basic_string<T>` corresponding.

The code was great, but as I read [somewhere](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3333.html#fingerprinting) the hash function may not be consistent over several executions of the same program. Moreover, I wanted to make this computation at compile-time, which was 1) not supported by `std::hash` and 2) would break code if `std::hash` return value changes.

So I wrote up the following implementation, based on [java.lang.String.hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29) implementation.

```
typedef size_t symbol;

template<typename CharT>
constexpr size_t constant_hash(const CharT* p, size_t h = 0) noexcept
{
    return (*p == 0) ? h : constant_hash(p + 1, h * 31 + static_cast<size_t>(*p));
}

constexpr symbol operator "" _sym (const char* p, size_t n) noexcept
{
    return constant_hash(p);
}
```

**My question is**: are there any problem with this implementation?

I'm only able to test it on GCC 4.7.1, and I'd like to know if it is standard-compliant and 
should also work on other compiler.

I'm asking this because a previous implementation was working on GCC but caused segfault if the binary was compiled with clang++ (problem of undefined behavior with increment operators I think).

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

Work with clang++ (thanks KennyTM)

Comment: I tried clang++ but it doesn't crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no UB, it works fine, as long as the string has `'\0'` termination. Note that `constexpr` evaluation cannot invoke UB; arithmetic or pointer operations that cause UB at runtime are required to produce a compile error in the context of a *constant-expression*.

Note that the `static_cast` is unnecessary; the `char` operand will be promoted to `size_t`.

Also, on first glance the hash function doesn't look very good because `h * 31` is just `( h << 5 ) - h`. You might pick a larger number with 1's randomly spread out across entire the binary value. But on the other hand, they might be trying to be clever since the low 5 bits of ASCII has the most entropy and this eliminates the possibility of collisions between short strings of different length.

Comment: Thanks for the precision concerning UB. The static_cast may still be usefull if constant_hash function is used with another type such as wchar_t or even anything else that could be casted to size_t, and as long as the array is zero-terminated. Concerning the hash function, you think I should replaced h*31 by (h << 5) - 1 ?

Comment: @Geoffroy: Potatoswatter means you could choose a better hash function, not replace `h*31` by `(h<<5)-h`. Java needs to use `h*31` because of backward compatibility, you don't.

Comment: Okay thanks for the precision, I didn't understand exactly what he means. Do you know any hash implementation satisfying the same conditions?

Comment: @Geoffroy Satisfying what same conditions? It's easy to find hash functions online. The one in `boost::hash_map` is a good start. For my high-performance string library, I got an extra performance boost from `std::size_t ret = static_cast< std::size_t >( 0x597316AC597316A9 ); for ( auto c : s ) ret *= c; return ret;`. It's all a balance between complexity and collisions.

Comment: I've found FNV hash, which is something like that. Thanks for the example :)

Comment: @Geoffroy Thanks for the link to FNV :)

Answer (score 2):

Note:  n3333 is a proposal for C++17.  While I don't believe there is a requirement for C++11 that hash produce the same result on multiple runs, in practice, I believe all current implementations do.

Comment: All implementation may do it for the moment, but C++1y may specify that the hash function change from one execution to another, just to prevent hazardous habits. Or simply specify that is must NOT change. We'll see :)

Answer (score 1):

In the current active C++ standard, the definition of a hash function in general is written that way to allow more possibilities for domain-specific implementations, rather than to require that hashes be performed in a particular way.  For example, it allows for the possibility of doing pooled strings and using the memory location of the pool instance as the hash value (incidentally, this is how ruby does its strings and hashes thereof, which has led to some [interesting issues](https://bandcamptech.wordpress.com/2010/01/21/how-not-to-generate-a-crc/)).  If you're computing your hash on the data, rather than the reference, then the value will be stable - unless you've discovered some form of math where constant expressions aren't.

Basically, "may not" is, in this case, *granting permission* for things to behave in a particular way, as opposed to stating what might happen.

That said, if you are using `std::hash`, you cannot guarantee that the values will always be the same between executions (and in the future, if n3333 is adopted, any code which relies on that *will break*), so it is better to define your own stable hash function if you require stable hashing.